# Правильно ли построено предложение? Возможно, требуются знаки препинания?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

При заказе стейков из говядины вы получаете бокал красного вина в подарок.

Comment: А в чем сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужны знаки препинания, это простое предложение.

При заказе стейков из говядины – обстоятельсвенный детерминант, относится ко всему предложению, запятой  не выделяется, хотя по смыслу он аналогичен придаточному предложению (если вы заказываете...).